# store kannel SMS into mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql, kannel

i have my Kannel.conf and sqlbox.conf well set up and working properly, I can send and receive messages properly except that now i want to store them in the database both the sent and received. Could some please show the scripts to save messages received and sent by kannel into MySql  database

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, but pure code requests are off topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: sms packed/unpacked? However, use base64 for storing into MySQL varchar column. Check  MySQLi or PDO_MySQL APIs for interacting with database.